# How to tokenize Spanish text with NLTK or Pattern-es

Tags: design-patterns, nlp, nltk, tokenize

Basically the issue I am having is with separating object and direct object pronouns from verbs.

Ie 'aprenderlo' should ideally be tokenized as two separate entities, 'dimelo' should be tokenized as three.  I have tried a variety of taggers in both libraries, and so far nothing has produced the results I want.  However, I am sure this must be a common problem - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like this is available by default in either library.

I ended up translating the relevant part of Stanford CoreNLP into Python.
https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/international/spanish/SpanishVerbStripper.java